# How to implement AUTO_INCREMENT properly in MonetDB?

Tags: sql, monetdb

I have two MonetDB tables using auto-increment to generate unique IDs for each row. Each row in the *child* table refers to one row in the *parent* table (modeling a 1:n relationship):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "test"."seq_parent" as integer START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE "test"."parent" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT next value for "test"."seq_parent",
    "name" STRING,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE SEQUENCE "test"."seq_child" as integer START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE "test"."child" (
    "id" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT next value for "test"."seq_child",
    "parent_id" INT NOT NULL,
    "name" STRING,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

When I import (parent, child_1, …, child_n) tuples to this database, I need first to `INSERT` the parent and then `INSERT` all the children using the ID of the parent I just created.

**The problem now is:** How do I get the ID of the row I just `INSERTed`? In MySQL, there is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for that. However, I could not find something like this in MonetDB.

I tried `SELECT next value for "test"."seq_parent"`, which gives an ID but increments the sequence at the same time. I also tried `SELECT MAX("id") FROM "test"."parent"` right after executing the `INSERT`, but this is fragile as it breaks if another client is connected and inserts data to the *parent* table at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use application code, do so.  First run a query to get the next value from seq_parent.  Then set it to a variable.  Then use that variable in all relevant insert commands.

Comment: In my case, the problem can indeed be solved by a combination of application code and a MonetDB sequence. Sometimes one doesn't see an obvious solution. Thank you for pointing this out!